# How to scroll to a certains element in a <li>

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have an application (to learn Meteor). 
I made a "blog" with news in the application. To modify my news,

Below is the journey

```
1.Click on Modify Link --> it works
2.Put a modify form on the bottom of the page --> it works
3.Save --> it works
4.Then i want to scroll to the item I've modified
```

There is the code

```
<li id="li">
<div>
    <img id="pic" src= {{photo}} />
</div>
<div>
    <label id="titreArticle">{{titre}}</label>
    {{#if isOwner}}
       {{#unless wantModif}}
    <button class="delete" style="color:black">&times;</button>
    <button class="modify" style="color:black">modify</button>
      {{/unless}}
    {{/if}}
    <p id="dateHeure"><strong>Ecrit par: {{username}} le {{date}} à {{heure}}</strong></p>
    <br>
</div>
<div id="textContenu">
    <span>{{text}}</span>
</div>
```

and i tried to do :

```
   Articles.find({_id: taskId}).scrollIntoView();
   window.scrollTo(0,Articles.find({_id: taskId}));
```

If someone could help me I'll be grateful

Comment: If an admin look these question could he delete it please ? I've found a right way to do what i wanted and this one is not clear

Answer (score 0):

you can just change the `location.hash` to scroll down to your ID

further reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

```js
$('#clickme').on('click', function() {
  $('p').last().after('<form id="modifyForm">Here is a supposed form<input type="submit" value="Bogus"/></form>');
  location.hash = '#modifyForm';
});
```

```css
p {
  font-style: italic;
}
form {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="clickme">Click me</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi a rhoncus velit. Curabitur ornare elementum dui non eleifend. Aliquam eleifend vestibulum ornare. Nullam ex lorem, tincidunt at est a, congue ornare dui. Donec fermentum, tortor eu mattis congue, ante massa pharetra purus, non tristique nunc nisi fringilla metus. Aliquam accumsan consequat ex maximus placerat. Quisque quis interdum eros. Donec ex nisl, ultricies sit amet feugiat vel, ullamcorper nec massa. Maecenas enim enim, tincidunt at tincidunt nec, fermentum sed metus. Curabitur dolor lacus, eleifend vitae bibendum quis, bibendum et turpis. Donec faucibus ligula sit amet eros dapibus porttitor.

<p>Nam id lorem non leo dictum rutrum. Fusce mollis eros consectetur urna accumsan pharetra. Nam posuere volutpat enim convallis tincidunt. Sed mi lectus, malesuada eu accumsan in, ornare at urna. Suspendisse potenti. Donec placerat lorem et maximus egestas. Nullam augue massa, ornare ac condimentum sed, venenatis et leo. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum ullamcorper convallis augue sed lacinia. Vestibulum in porttitor quam. Pellentesque bibendum leo eu diam accumsan, sit amet pharetra dui sollicitudin. Donec consequat massa est, et iaculis risus dictum ac.

<p>Pellentesque eu sapien dignissim, tempor odio ut, tempus quam. Integer condimentum sapien massa, ac cursus ipsum semper viverra. Proin et rutrum elit, ac placerat ex. Aenean vulputate diam quis magna viverra, et porta leo vestibulum. Aliquam diam velit, ornare at tellus non, dapibus ornare urna. Donec ultricies est placerat lorem ullamcorper, sit amet molestie quam facilisis. Fusce vehicula mollis facilisis. Donec vitae interdum dolor. Fusce euismod lacus eget arcu tempor, nec laoreet ex varius. Praesent in rutrum tellus.

<p>Phasellus a ex mauris. Pellentesque odio eros, luctus vitae eros sit amet, consectetur vestibulum nisi. Morbi purus massa, accumsan nec magna vel, ornare euismod libero. Sed pellentesque, dui non semper facilisis, ante metus tincidunt velit, sit amet gravida arcu dolor egestas massa. Etiam imperdiet ipsum tincidunt lorem convallis, at pharetra ligula pretium. Etiam condimentum et nisi id interdum. Donec accumsan massa non viverra ultricies. Ut quis porta magna. Ut in efficitur augue, a varius augue. Fusce ipsum nulla, ornare vel semper vitae, tempor quis dui. Pellentesque vitae elit tincidunt, tincidunt ligula id, pharetra ante. Nam commodo vehicula felis quis sollicitudin. Praesent non tristique leo.

<p>Maecenas mollis augue sit amet risus faucibus facilisis. Sed odio lacus, venenatis et tincidunt a, congue eu tellus. Nam non blandit erat. Etiam et urna et lorem pellentesque porttitor. Quisque tristique accumsan risus a mollis. Donec cursus molestie ornare. Pellentesque pharetra, quam vitae placerat pulvinar, quam enim suscipit nulla, at sollicitudin metus mi in massa. Pellentesque gravida blandit turpis, ac sagittis magna pretium eget. Aliquam convallis tempus lectus, quis semper lectus efficitur ut. Fusce tincidunt cursus sem. Duis quis porttitor ex, sit amet maximus erat. Proin sit amet lobortis lectus, at eleifend nisl. Duis nec facilisis lacus, tincidunt lacinia urna. Quisque a efficitur erat. Vivamus feugiat velit nisi, eu consectetur turpis dignissim id. Donec hendrerit metus eget elit sollicitudin auctor.
```

Comment: Thank you @arhak but yeah i can't do it with your method

Answer (score 0):

You can get the top position of the element and [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) there:

```
var top = $('#titreArticle').position().top;
$(window).scrollTop( top );
```

A working example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/eITuQgFqc1ksPffClywI?p=preview).

Comment: Hi, thank you but your solution just bring me to the top of the page but i want to go to the location of the news i modified

Comment: if you put your newly changed div id in the selector it takes you to that item, see the update @Jerome

Comment: it still bring me to the top of the articles list...
I would do something like until titleModified == document.getElementybyid(titleArticle) check the next one then when titleModified==docu... scrollTo it

Comment: If you have unique ids for those it should work really easy. Check the update and the plunkr @Jerome

Comment: you pointed out the problem all articles have the same pattern https://plnkr.co/edit/vSqmOKKWucMsn0dJK8c5?p=preview so as you can see i have no unique id for each article... @yaser

Comment: As far as I can see you have an id for that label inside your div which cannot be duplicated or you will get an error. can't you use that? @Jerome

Comment: Hm i can use my application but when i modify an element for the moment it bring me to the top of the page but i would go to the modified element location. And with the code you gave me it bring me to the first element so the top of the list